# Purpose of `return self` from a class method?

Tags: python, method-chaining

I came across something like this in an open-source project. Methods that modify instance attributes return a reference to the instance. What is the purpose of this construct?

```
class Foo(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self.myattr = 0

  def bar(self):
    self.myattr += 1
    return self
```

Comment: And this is how pretty much all of jQuery is written.  Nearly every function returns a jQuery object

Comment: Why wouldn't you trust code written like that?

Answer (score 69):

It's to allow chaining.

For example:

```
var Car = function () {
    return {
        gas : 0,
        miles : 0,
        drive : function (d) {
            this.miles += d;
            this.gas -= d;
            return this;
        },
        fill : function (g) {
            this.gas += g;
            return this;
        },
    };
}
```

Now you can say:

```
var c = Car();
c.fill(100).drive(50);
c.miles => 50;
c.gas => 50;
```

Comment: for the record, this kind of chaining is generally seen on code with [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: among the few times I upvote an answer in another language!

Answer (score 11):

As @Lie Ryan and @Frank Shearar mention, that's called a "fluent interface" but that pattern has been around for a really long time.

The controversial part of that pattern is that in OO, you have mutable state, so a void method has a kind of implied return value of `this` -- that is, the object with updated state is kind of the return value.

So in an OO language with mutable state, these two are more or less equivalent:

```
a.doA()
a.doB()
a.doC()
```

...as opposed to

```
a.doA().doB().doC()
```

So I've heard people in the past resist fluent interfaces because they like the first form. Another name I've heard for "fluent interface" is "train wreck" ;)

I say "more or less equivalent", though, because fluent interfaces add a wrinkle. They don't have to "return this". They can "return new". That's a way of attaining immutable objects in OO.

So you could have a class A that does (pseudocode)

```
function doA():
    return new A(value + 1)

function doB():
    return new A(value * 2)

function doC():
    return new A(sqrt(value))
```

Now, each method returns a brand new object, leaving the initial object unchanged. And that's a way of getting into immutable objects without really changing much in your code.

Comment: Ok but if your methods return `new(...)`, that would leak memory.

Comment: @smci That would depend heavily on the language, implementation, and usage. Sure, if it's C++, you'll likely be leaking memory all over the place. But this would all be trivially cleaned up by a language with a garbage collector. Some implementations (with or without GC) may even detect when one of those new objects aren't used and just not actually allocate anything.

Comment: @8bittree: we're talking about Python, this question was tagged Python 8 years ago. Python GC is not great so best not to leak memory in the first place. Calling `__init__` repeatedly  introduces overhead too.

Answer (score 8):

Most language are aware of the 'return self' idiom, and ignore it if it is 
not used in a line. However it is notable that in Python, functions
return `None` by default.

When I was in CS school my instructor made a *huge* deal about
the difference between functions, procedures, routines, and methods; many hand-cramping essay questions were ground out with mechanical pencils getting hot in  my hands about all that.

Suffice it to say, returning self is the definitive OO way to craft
class methods, but Python allows for multiple return values, tuples, lists, objects, primitives, or None.

Chaining, as they put it, is merely putting the answer to the last operation into the next, and the runtime of Python can optimize that kind of thing. List comprehensions are a built-in form of this. (Very powerful!)

So in Python it is not so important that every method or function return things,
which is why the default is None.

There is a school of thought that every action in a program should report its success, failure, or result back to its invoking context or object, but then
were not talking DOD ADA Requirements here.  If you need to get feedback from
a method, go ahead, or not, but try to be consistent about it.

If a method can fail, it should return success or failure or raise an exception to be handled.

One caveat is that if you use the return self idiom, Python will allow you to assign all your methods to variables and you might think you are getting a data result or a list when you are actually getting the object.

Type-restrictive languages scream and yell and break when you try to do this, but interpreted ones (Python, Lua, Lisp) are much more dynamic.

Answer (score 5):

In Smalltalk, every method that doesn't explicitly return something, has an implicit "return self".

That's because (a) having every method return something makes the computing model more uniform and (b) it's very useful having methods return self. Josh K gives a nice example.

Comment: Interesting ... in `Python`, every method that doesn't explicitly return something, has an implicit "return None".

Comment: looks like: `smalltalk >> python`.   I've done zero smalltalk and years of python.

Answer (score 2):

## Pros of returning an object (`return self`)

- Example:

  ```
  print(foo.modify1().modify2())

  # instaed of
  foo.modify1()
  foo.modify2()
  print(foo)
  ```
- More popular style in programming community (I think).

## Pros of mutating an object (no `return self`)

- Ability to use `return` for other purposes.
- *Guido van Rossum* [approves of this style](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-October/038855.html) (I disagree with his argument).
- More popular style in Python community (I think).
- Default (less source code).

Comment: The Guido arguement is compelling to me. Particular the part where he  talks about "the reader must be intimately familiar with each of the methods"   I.e. It forces you need to determine if  this a self chain or and output chain or a combo before you understand what you  have at the end of the chain

Comment: @Nat How string processing operations fundamentally differ from the rest of the operations?

Comment: The difference is that the string case your are generating a new completely different object each time.  I.e. Not modifying the item in place. it's clear that  the existing object isn't being modified.   In  a language where return self is implicit the opposite is true but  the mixed environment seems problematic

Comment: @Matt I just remembered that Python strings are immutable. That fully answers my question.

Comment: @Matt "it's clear that the existing object isn't being modified" - it is not clear just from looking though.

Comment: The problem with chaining comes from when some methods return the identity object, others return a new object that is of the same type and others return some other thing entirely.  When using a language where all return types of methods are declared, this is mitigated to some extent.  I've seen it work well but it requires very consistent idioms.

Comment: I can't recall a single controversial topic in which I sided with Guido. He's gone now .. I think?