# For instance methods, would always returning self or this, instead of using a void return type, be a clean coding style?

Tags: methods, return-type, method-chaining

I just came across [this article](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29657/purpose-of-return-self-from-a-class-method), and in particular, [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/29661/100669).  Essentially they're talking about returning `self` from instance methods to allow for method chaining.  That being said, one of the first thoughts that came to mind was, *Why not always take instance methods with `void` return types and make them return `this` or `self` instead?*  The next thought, which came to mind immediately, was, *There's probably a reason this isn't more common.*  So what could be the harm in it?

It seems like there honestly wouldn't be any.  The reason is that nothing about the mere existence of a return value implies or even seems to imply the need to use that return value.  If the method is a specialized getter or file reader or something, that's one thing, but if people aren't looking to use the return value, they naturally won't pay one any attention.  Furthermore it shouldn't be too confusing, because `return this;` is pretty trivial; at most, somebody would probably think it's irrelevant.  It certainly seems like it wouldn't hurt anything, and it's generally better to have too much than too little.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Discuss this ${blog}](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/discuss-this-blog)**

Comment: It's not done more often because it's a convention that would be useless most of the time, misleading some of the time, misused half of the time, and unnoticed when actually relevant.  It goes against YAGNI.

Comment: I am not sure there is anything constructive to add that is not already covered in the question/answers to which you linked.

Comment: re: your update.  If I'm working with an API, I *will* be checking return types.  If I expect `void` and see something else then I'll stop and think about why it's not void.  If there's no good reason other than "why not?" then I'll be left scratching my head about it.  After all, why would something like `gameComponent.Draw()` return a `GameComponent`?  If you aren't going to need it, then don't do it.  It just adds unneeded complexity and additional points of failure.

Comment: @gnat I would make more use of posts like that, but there's not a very clear line though between what is and is not acceptable on P.SE.  Posts like that seem to rule out every on-subject question for this site; if a question is conceptual, and not about a black-and-white, it is or it isn't, true or false technical question, then there's always some post like that that goes against it.  But that's the very same thing that's supposed to separate P.SE questions from SO ones.  Then somebody comes along and writes a post about what is acceptable...but they seem to list many of the same things.

Comment: @MetaFight Still thinking about what you said; the update was to make the question sound a little less nubish.

Comment: @Panzercrisis: Your question would be a better one if it didn't simply boil down to "is this good or bad?"  There's a difference between questions that examine the relative merit of specific technical issues, and ones that merely discuss opinions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I start to see your point, except that good vs. bad seems like an important part of conceptual questions in general, and it seems that other questions that have resolved down to this have been welcomed in the past.  In general though, if there were a clearer line in the dust, just so that people could see exactly where it was, I would probably be much more careful about stepping over it.  I think a lot of people would.  No offense is intended.

Comment: @Panzercrisis: In general, questions need to be *answerable.*  Book recommendations are not answerable.  "Is this good or bad" is not answerable.  "What term is used for this" is often not answerable; not everything has a term, and all the person wants is something to Google, not our expertise.  Etc.  The "what is this called thing" is a new thing, but it's clearly not community-friendly.  Sometimes we have to add new rules for new ways that people find to abuse online communities (the number of such ways is nearly unbounded).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, methods returning `void` should be uncommon. Why? It means that for the method to do anything meaningful, it needs to mutate the class or have some other side effect. Mutations and side effects generally cause trouble with concurrency, testing, and reasoning about the correctness of your program.

Worse, the trend in modern object oriented programming is to favor immutable objects more and more. What does the function signature look for methods that do some operation and then return a new form of the object (think `DateTime.AddHours`)? That's right, the same as some self returning mutating function.

And in general, ignoring return values is a code smell, often obscuring error handling or other errors.

In short - it *can* lead to clean code if that is the idiom in your language/environment, but is a bad idea in general, going against the trends of best practices.

Comment: Method chaining does not guarantee purity.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - no, it pretty much guarantees impurity if you're converting `void` methods.